# Trying to remove all the passed dates

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array with many dates, they are not in the date type but string like: "2016-08-12" for example. Then what I would like to do is to remove all dates that we already have passed. So therefor im trying to compare them to todays date and then remove it if its passed. Using typescript by the way.

my array, named datoArray, looks like this:

["2016-08-02", "2016-08-11", "2016-08-22", "2016-09-10"]

just with a lot more of the same...

then here's what I try to do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.datoArray.length; i++){
    this.skoleAar = parseInt(this.datoArray[i].slice(0,4))
    this.skoleMaaned = parseInt(this.datoArray[i].slice(5,8))
    this.skoleDag = parseInt(this.datoArray[i].slice(8,10))

        if(this.skoleAar < dagensAar){
            this.datoArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
        if(this.skoleAar == dagensAar && this.skoleMaaned < dagensMaaned){
            this.datoArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
        if(this.skoleAar == dagensAar && this.skoleMaaned == dagensMaaned && this.skoleDag < dagensDag){
            this.datoArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
```

the "dagensAar", "dagensMaaned" and "dagensDag" variables im getting from another function that works. If i "console.log" the variables it prints out int values like 2016 for the year and 8 for the month if i take from the start of the array, and for the "dagensAar", "dagensMaaned" and "dagensDag" it prints 2016 11 20, which is todays year, month and day. all is in Int type, so what im not getting here is why my "if" doesnt work? It seems like there is something wrong with the way i compare the, but i thought this was the way to compare int values?

Comment: it looks like it is going into the if statement, but you are changing the contents of the `datoArray` while you are looping over it which is going to cause some problems. I would suggest creating a new array and adding all valid dates to the new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dates are in ISO-8601 format then you can simply filter using [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

```js
var dates = ["2016-08-02", "2016-08-11", "2016-08-22", "2016-09-10", "2016-12-15"];

function removePastDates(data) {
  var today = new Date();
  console.log('Initial state: ' + data);
  var modified = dates.filter(function(dateString) {
    return Date.parse(dateString) >= today;
  });
  console.log('Final state: ' + modified);
  return modified;
}

var newDates = removePastDates(dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dates seem to be RFC compliant, meaning they can be directly fed into a new `Date` object. Simply compare to today and filter by that:

```
var today = new Date()
var futureDates = this.datoArray.filter(d => new Date(d) >= today)
```

(pre-ECMA6:)

```
var today = new Date()
var futureDates = this.datoArray.filter(function (d) {
  return new Date(d) >= today;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not related to the dates.

I think the problem is that you are removing items from the array while looping the same exact array.

You should maybe try looping from the end of the array to the beginning or just save the indexes that you need to remove and later do the actual removing.
Keep in mind that when you remove an item you change the index of every item in the remaining of the array - maybe you should start removing from the greatest index so it will not confuse you.

Comment: This would be a a good comment if summarized, not an answer though

Comment: @casraf Thanks for the comment, I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: Rule of thumb is it shouldn't be an answer if it doesn't have working code inside :)